# How to access mapped network drive from ssh?

Tags: windows, batch-file, ssh

I have a script which sshes to a windows box. The script expects certain mapped drives to be available but fails as it is unable to access it. On investigating further, I realized that the mapped drive is actually unavailable when I view it via ssh in contrast to when I see it locally. As an example

```
C:\Users\username>net use
New connections will be remembered.


Status       Local     Remote                    Network

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             Y:        \\path\subpath             Microsoft Windows Network
The command completed successfully.


C:\Users\username>ssh localhost "net use"
Could not create directory '/home/username/.ssh'.
The authenticity of host 'localhost (::1)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 7b:52:27:8f:19:ea:22:c4:0e:a2:7d:30:4f:3b:7d:d3.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/username/.ssh/known_hos
ts).
username@localhost's password:
New connections will be remembered.


Status       Local     Remote                    Network

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Unavailable  Y:        \\path\subpath             Microsoft Windows Network
```

So my question is, how to access a mapped drive from ssh

**Note** The target OS is Windows 2012 R2

Comment: Try using `more \\path\subpath\file.txt` maybe?

Comment: @MarkSetchell: You mean to use UNC? I know it is a option, but for me it is a costly option as it stands now. So trying to know, why the mapped drive does not work.

Comment: Maybe this will help... https://fogbugz.bitvise.com/default.asp?WinSSHD.1.19930.4